# Asus TUF laptop and Ubuntu 20.04/21.10 - Bluetooth not turning ON

Tags: bluetooth, laptop, asus

I got a new ASUS TUF Gaming Laptop FX506LH and went ahead and installed Ubuntu along with Windows. Everything seems OK, but the bluetooth simply wont turn ON. I tried cold boot and also the modprobe fixes that worked for many. But for me, whatever I do it doesn't turn ON.  Any help would be highly appreciated as I want to use Ubuntu as the daily driver in this and having bluetooth is critical to that.
Tried Ubuntu 20.04 and 21.10 - same behavior in both.

Note: Have another laptop from Asus (Vivobook S15) where this just works fine with Ubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows.

Comment: Are you sure the machine in question has Bluetooth hardware and that it is turned on in hardware?

Comment: Definitely. I connected a headset and listened to music in Windows 11 on the same laptop.